# Seeking a recommendation for a (preferably free) Project Management app?

Tags: app

I am looking for a a recommendation for a (preferably free) Project Management app in Salesforce.

I am interested in setting up a system that would allow users to track internal projects on Salesforce, log calls/emails/notes to the project, and generally increase collaboration. I think this would be similar to cases, except that it would not necessarily involve any client or external contact.

Anyone have any suggestions for apps I should look into?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls avoid questions which are discussion oriented. You would be downvoted.

Comment: I was actually hoping for a very short, concise answer. That being the name of a Project Management app. Discussion might only develop if the community engaged in the discussion, which could then be regulated by upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the place for getting recommendations on products, this might actually get people to misuse to advertise their products. Not suggesting anyone did it here but there is a huge possibility of that.This should probably be a discussion point in Meta on allowing these kind of questions. My view is that the questions should be precise on problem you are facing and not be open ended question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for free, why not build yourself? A lot of my clients use [Milestones PM](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003ItrEEAS) as a base and customize it to their needs. It wouldn't be hard to do it from scratch either. This way, you get exactly what you want and if it's great, you can share (or sell) it later!

Comment: Thanks, gonna check out Milestones PM in more detail and see about customizing it.

Answer (score 5):

[Bracket Labs](http://www.bracketlabs.com) produces a project management app for SFDC: [TaskRay](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000055lKwEAI). Well it's not free, we do offer a free trial, it's a huge productivity booster, with chatter built right in.

[Milestones PM](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003ItrEEAS) on the AppExchange is also popular, but has a less intuitive user interface. There is also a paid version: [Milestones PM+](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009uYYMEA2)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty on [App Exchange](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/) You should take a look there and of-course [Milestone PM](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003ItrEEAS) is the best and free as provided by Force.com Labs.

Comment: Hey Ankit - you don't need a 'sig' in your posts - folks can click through to see your profile.

Comment: Got it, will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

[Milestones PM](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003ItrEEAS) is definitely a good app. You may also love to have look at 
[Do.Com](http://Do.com)

Answer (score 1):

There's also do.com. It's owned by Salesforce.com They acquired Manymoon.com a year or two ago and rebranded and touched it up. It's a separate app and a separate login from Salesforce. Currently there's virtually no integration with force.com. I imagine that will change in the future (safe harbor).

It has Chatter-like conversations and supports task management, uploads, and a lot of other features common to web-based project management tools. I've only noodled with it a bit but found it to be pretty user friendly and useful.

[edit 2 days later]
There's a free app on the AppExchange that provides some info sharing between SFDC and do.com:
http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000007rBeOEAU

Answer (score 0):

A couple of folks mentioned Do.com.  Unfortunately, on January 31, 2014, the Do.com service will be discontinued.  Information can (for now) be found here: https://do.com/done